# TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes. Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered

Tags: expo, sanity

I have created a file to connect data from my sanity project to my app with the following code:

```
import { ImageUrlBuilder } from "@sanity/image-url";
import { createClient } from "@sanity/client";

const client = createClient({
    projectId: 'project_id',
    dataset: 'production',
    useCdn: true,
    apiVersion: '2022-01-12', 
});

const builder = ImageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);

export default client;
```

But when i tried running the code, I get the error saying:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes  ERROR
> Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen
> if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

If anyone is knowledgable in using Sanity.io any help would be greatly appreaciated.